# Chaco marker properties

Tags: python, plot, chaco

I am looking for a way to use empty circles as markers in Chaco (something like using markeredgecolor in matplotlib).  Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find a list of properties that can be passed to enthought.chaco.api.Plot.plot() to do that, so does anyone know how to do that?  (A pointer to a decent Chaco doc would be even nicer...)
Thanks,
Antony

Answer (score 0):

When in doubt, always turn to the src-code :-)
It looks like Plot is implemented [here](https://github.com/enthought/chaco/blob/master/chaco/plot.py) and the src-code is heavily commented, including examples.

Just out of curiosity  (since I'm a big fan of matplotlib), why chako, does it offer something not available in matplotlib? :-)

Comment: I have also used matplotlib a lot, and really like it (and its good documentation...), however I am trying to buid a GUI, and the integration of Chaco with traits seems potentially useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
plot.plot(("index", "value", "color"),
    type="cmap_scatter",
    name="my_plot",
    color_mapper=jet,
    marker = "square",
    fill_alpha = 0.5,
    marker_size = 6,
    outline_color = "black")
```

The above is directly from the chaco example cmap_scatter.py: [Annotated Chaco Examples](http://code.enthought.com/projects/chaco/docs/html/user_manual/annotated_examples.html)